how to bundle mitmproxy executable with its python script using pyinstaller
I am adding mitmproxy executable bundle in client side machine which runs on background but my issue is since I want to intercept and modify network traffic and the command for doing so require .py script mitmproxy -s proxy.py so how can I protect this file from user then because its executable require python file as well ?
Example python script is:
from mitmproxy import http
from mitmproxy.tools.main import mitmdump

async def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.method == 'GET':
            flow.response = http.Response.make(
            200,  
            b"Hello World",  
            {"Content-Type": "text/html","access-control-allow-origin": "*"},
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mitmdump(['-p', '9999', '-s', 'proxy.py', '--set', 'client_replay_concurrency=-1', '--set', 'websocket=false'])


I bundled using pyinstaller command pyinstaller --onefile proxy.py but the above script finds for .py file and mitmproxy need to read it raw it understand it.
How can I protect this file from client machine. Is there a way to bundle it up on the build or something.
Please help me with this.

I don't think the additional script requires execute bit. Have you tried it? What do you mean by "protect", there are multiple possibilities what protect could mean in this context (not execute, not read, not modify, ...).

It actually means if i am making a python bundle exe then i don't want any code to be readable in py script. But after making the above code to exe, the exe still require the .py script which is a big issue if i want to deploy it in client end and not in server end. As client can read the script and even change it.

+1 I added this in mitmproxy github discussion section and the developer told me that it isn't supported at this point. They also gave a small workaround(which require to folk mitmproxy and adding script internally) but said the workaround is not recommended and can cause issues.
